# how should i access n number of different .mat file in r by setting a proper path?

Tags: r, matlab

I have a total of 121 .mat files for some sonar experiment. I want to read each mat file by the iterative way and each iteration I want to access data from one particular mat file and work on corresponding data. I had already done with Matlab code the same thing I am trying in r.

This is my Matlab code

```
myFolder = 'G:\minor_project\Indrajeet\Data\ExpData\SingleChannel with 
Array Steering\16 cell mesh slanting 30 deg';

% Check to make sure that the folder actually exists. Warn user if it doesn't.

if ~isdir(myFolder)
 errorMessage = sprintf('Error: The following folder does notexist:\n%s', myFolder);
 uiwait(warndlg(errorMessage));
 return;
end
 fpath = dir(fullfile( myFolder, '*.mat'));

 filenames = fullfile(myFolder, {fpath.name});
```

Now if you observe carefully fpath variable you will find the first fullfile function takes myFolfer where my path is store and result in following or build full file name including .mat extension.

```
 G:\minor_project\Indrajeet\Data\ExpData\SingleChannel with Array 
 Steering\16 cell mesh slanting 30 deg\*.mat
```

then "dir" function use the same folder name to create the list of (in the form of the structure of 121x1 struct which later I am accessing using dot.operator) all data.

Now I am learning the r programming and tried to mimic the same logic which is made in Matlab and initiated as

```
library(R.matlab)

myFolder = "G:/minor_project/Indrajeet/Data/ExpData/SingleChannel with 
Array Steering/16 cell mesh slanting 30 deg";

if(!file.exists(myFolder))
{
 print("Error: The following folder does not exist")
}
```

currently I know the "readMat" function only,is there any functions whcih will work same as fullfile and dir in r?if so,whcih packages this function belongs to

Comment: If I understand you correctly you need an object that will have the list of mat files in your folder. do this, `mat_data_files <- list.files(path = myFolder, pattern = "*.mat", full.names = TRUE). read up `?list.files`

Comment: @infominer ya you understand me correctly, your suggestion works and I am able to create the object of the list of mat files and can able to access my data. Thanks a lot.

Comment: cool, glad you got it to work